# Submitting and validating a form that flashes messages if successful

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I am trying to validate the register form but I can't seem to make a connection to allow AJAX to valid the form. So far, the validation errors are in the `Validate.php` file and in the `signup.php` file are the validation rules.

Below is my code:
Validate.php

```
<?php

class Validate {

private $_passed = false,
    $_errors = array(),
    $_db = null;

public function __construct() {

$this->_db = DB::getInstance();

}

public function check($source, $items = array('name')) {

foreach($items as $item => $rules) {

    foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

        $value = trim($source[$item]);
        $item = escape($item);

        if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {

            $this->addError("{$item} is required");

        }

        else if (!empty($value)) {
            switch($rule) {
                case 'min':
                    if (strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                        $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                    }
                break;
                case 'max':
                    if (strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                        $this->addError("{$item} has a maximum of {$rule_value} character limit.");
                    }
                break;
                case 'unique':
                    $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                    if($check->count()) {
                        $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                    };
                break;
                case 'matches':
                    if ($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                        $this->addError("Your entry does not match {$item}.");
                    }
                break;

            }
        }

    }

}

if(empty($this->_errors)) {

        $this->_passed = true;

    }

return $this;

}

private function addError($error) {

$this->_errors[] = $error;

}

public function errors() {

return $this->_errors;

}

public function passed() {

return $this->_passed;

}

}
```

signup.php

```
if (Input::exists()) {

if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'First Name' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'max' => 40
                ),
            'last_name' => array(
                'name' => 'Last Name',
                'required' => true,
                'max' => 40
                ),
            'email' => array(
                'name' => 'Email',
                'required' => true,
                'max' => 50,
                'unique' => 'users'
                ),
            'password' => array(
                'name' => 'Password',
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 6,
                'max' => 30
                ),
            'c_psw' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'matches' => 'password'
                )
        ));

    if ($validation->passed()) {

        //register user
        Session::flash('success', 'You have registered successfully. Please check your email inbox for the activation email. Please also check your Junk email folder just in case the activation email was sent there instead of your inbox.');

    }

    else {

        //output errors
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {

            echo $error, '<br>';

        }

    }

}
```

And if it helps: this is the Input.php file:

```
class Input {
//exists
public static function exists ($type = 'post') {

    switch($type) {

        case 'post':
            return(!empty($_POST)) ? true :false;
        break;
        case 'get':
            return(!empty($_GET)) ? true :false;
        break;
        default:
            return false;
        break;

    }

}
//get
public static function get($item) {

    if(isset($_POST[$item])) {

        return $_POST[$item];

    }

    else if(isset($_GET[$item])) {

        return $_GET[$item];

    }

    return '';

}
```

}

Comment: So you're flashing the message to the session but you're not actually returning said message?

Comment: It's more along the lines of I want to use AJAX validation than using the validation I'm using right now. Since the form action is signup.php, once I submit, it goes to signup.php and shows a blank page. I want to submit the form and then redirect back to index.php with the validation errors and change css borders of fields that have errors. And if successful, a flash message will appear and then fade out or immediately disappear if you click the greyish transparent empty space.

Comment: Where is your jquery/js?

Comment: if validation->passed() == true then nothing is returned to the browser. You just write a value to the session. If you want something to go back to the browser via ajax you need to echo it (just like you do when validation fails).